# How to use "confidential mode" of gmail using JavaMailSender

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-send-email-via-smtp/) for setting up mail sender through spring-boot

I have been trying to add [confidential mode](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/prevent-emails-forwarded-outlook-gmail/) through spring boot, there is no specific method as all supported mail providers not following the same method so using MimeMessage there is no predefined function.

I tried to look at the header of mail message which was sent in "confidential mode", so if they have added the confidential mode setup in the header, I would set header something like

```
helper.getMimeMessage().setHeader("Confidential", "on");
helper.getMimeMessage().setHeader("expiry", "5y");
```

But, they are not providing it through the header

1. So, what can be done to achieve "confidential mode" programmatically?

Comment: My understanding is that confidential mode is implemented entirely within Gmail and not exposed to applications outside of Gmail.  There's no way for an application outside of Gmail to send a confidential mode message.  A confidential message sent to a recipient outside of Gmail appears as a message with a link to view the content in Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For visibility purposes I'm addressing Bill Shannon comment which is totally correct. Gmail confidential mode its designed to be used within Gmail. If you use any other Email client to open a "confidential email" it will open a new window to open the message within Gmail.
  For more information, check the following link https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7674059.
- I have checked within the list of possible API calls in [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) with the scope: 
  `https://mail.google.com/`
  which is the biggest scope for `user.messages` (which includes `send` and `modify` API calls), and I was unable to see any calls nor fields related to compose of confidential messages. Nor any documentation in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send).
- I have tested on my domain, and I was able to see that the messages on the recipient side has an additional header X-Gm-Locker which is generated by Gmail internally.

Remember that if you want to send a message with this feature, you need to enable "Confidential mode"  in Google Console https://support.google.com/a/answer/7684332?hl=en.

**TL;DR:**
In a nutshell, you can't send messages with "Confidential mode" through the Gmail API. Which affects the usage of JavaMailSender.

Comment: I also saw the header. But, the header is only available when message sent to 
 different mail client. Within Google, there is no trace of confidential mode in header(3 dot > show original). But the link you shared https://support.google.com/a/answer/7684332?hl=en , there in Create a compliance rule to block incoming messages it is shown to match metadata  Gmail confidential mode. If it not shown in header(mail between same domain ), then how can one filter?

Comment: No, the header X-Gm-Locker will be added independently of the mail client that you use and this is how you can filter these messages, by the existence of this header. My test consisted in sending confidential message inside and outside acc from my G Suite domain, and from inside, recipient with/without this feature disabled.

Remember that you can visualize the raw data of any email (RFC compliant) in any email client (RFC Compliant). There is no way for Gmail to tell how this message its gonna be visualized on the recipient side. (You can see this by, clicking on (Download Original)).

Comment: However, please feel free to file a Feature Request for this functionality stating your use case and the importance of this feature.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107